# Partitions of convex planar regions into zonogons

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

A **zonogon** is a centrally symmetric convex polygon.

1. Are there convex *non-zonogons* that can be partitioned into a finite number of (convex) zonogons?
2. Same as 1 with the pieces allowed to be nonconvex but centrally symmetric polygons.

Comment: Interesting question! I can imagine that this has an answer in terms of zonotopal subdivisions. In my head I have a rather vague argument that if you partition a polygon only into rhombuses, then it should be possible to consider this as the projection of a zonotope, where the tiles are projections of certain faces. The zonotope is centrally symmetric, and so the polygon must be centrally symmetric too. Perhaps there is another argument that shows that any non-rhombic tile can be further subdivided into rhombuses, which gives a rhombic partition.

Comment: This seems to hold even if the tiles are no longer connected. For example, I can use one tile that is the disjoint union of two triangles, as long as these triangles are point reflections of each other. Stated differently, it seems that a polygon that can be partitioned into only centrally symmetric polygons, and further polygons that appear in point-reflected pairs, is itself centrally symmetric. What if the tiles can have holes? What if we ask the same in higher dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

I extend on the answer of Yaakov Baruch.

Choose a generic direction as being "down". We can then speak of *bottom edges* and *top edges* of the polygon and its tiles.

Suppose that the polygon $P$ is partitioned into convex tiles, so that there exists a perfect matching between the tiles that are *not* centrally symmetric and matched tiles are related by a central point reflection (see the figure below).
Assume further that the partition is edge-to-edge, that is, no vertex of one tile meets an edge of another tile (Yaakov explained why this is no restriction).

Let $e_0$ be a top edge.
Note that every edge is the top-edge of at most one tile.
We construct a sequence of edges $e_1,...,e_m$ of edges as follows:

- if $e_i$ is the top edge of a centrally symmetric tile $T$, then let $e_{i+1}$ be the "opposite" bottom edge of $T$.
- if $e_i$ is the top edge of not-centrally symmetric tile $T$, then let $e_{i+1}$ be the corresponding edge in the matched tile to $T$. $e_{i+1}$ is then a bottom edge of the matched tile.
- if $e_i$ is not the top edge of any tile, then $e_i$ is a bottom edge of $P$.

Note that all edges in this sequence are of the same length and have the same orientation, and so each top edge of $P$ corresponds to an equally long and equally oriented bottom edge. Since $P$ is convex, the order of these edges at the bottom must be inverse to the order at the top. This shows that $P$ must be centrally symmetric.

[image]

Note that this formulation includes the case of *non-convex* tiles.
Every centrally symmetric tile can be decomposed into a set of convex centrally symmetric tiles and a set of pairs of matched convex tiles that are not necessarily centrally symmetric:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any centrally symmetric convex polygon can be sudbivided into rhombuses, so assume only rhombuses are used. Now split them further (with lines parallel to the edges) so that no vertex of a rhombus falls in the middle of the edge of an adjacent rhombus. (This is clearly a finite process.) Then each *bottom* segment (according to a fixed arbitrary choice of vertical direction) into which the overall perimeter is now divided is matched with one and only one parallel *top* segment **of the same length** on the opposite side, by following a unique path edge-to-opposite-edge one rhombus at a time. By convexity, all parallel segments (of different length) are together on the both bottom and top sides (but possibly in different orders). Therefore the total length for each direction is the same on the two opposite sides.

**UPDATE.** The proof above of 1. can carry on to 2. as well. In fact there is no need for the components to be rhombi or to be convex, and no need to *cut* them. All that is needed instead is to *label* the segments into which an edge is split by a vertex, and to replicate that splitting and labeling in the opposite edge (notice: in a centrally symmetric way this time!). And so on, propagate all vertex points inside edges through all opposite parallel edges. When that is done, in a finite number of steps, once again thanks to the overall convexity, there will be paths creating a one-to-one (non order-preserving) correspondence between *top* and *bottom* segments with same direction and length, proving the overall central symmetry.

[image: Example with segment paths.]

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that every centrally symmetric polygon can be partitioned into rhombuses?

Comment: @M.Winter : assume it's a $2n$-agon. One can start from a vertex and clockwise peel off a rhombus at a time along the edge; after removing $n$ rhombuses one is left with a $(2n-2)$-agon.

Comment: Correction: in the comment above the inductive step involves removing $n-1$, rather than $n$, rhombi.